# Find which fields are different between two instances of the same Model

Tags: django, django-models

Well, I think the question explains itself.

I have two instances of a Django Model and I would like to know which fields differ.

How could you do this in a smart way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lets says `obj1` and `obj2` are 2 instances of the model `MyModel`.

To know which fields differ on two instances of a Django model, we first get all the fields of a model and store it in a variable `my_model_fields`.

```
my_model_fields = MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names() # gives me the list of all the model fields defined in it
```

Then we apply `filter()` with `lambda` to know which fields differ between them.

```
filter(lambda field: getattr(obj1,field,None)!=getattr(obj2,field,None), my_model_fields)
```

The `filter()` function will return me the list of model fields which differ between the two instances.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried:      
       my_model_fields = self._meta.get_all_field_names() # gives me the list of all the model fields defined in it
            filter(lambda field: getattr(self,field,None)!=getattr(orig,field,None), my_model_fields)
... Which is called in the save method of an instance, but I get: NameError self global name is not defined... Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind! If I do changed_fields = filter(lambda field: getattr(obj1,field,None)!=getattr(obj2,field,None), my_model_fields) I get back the changed fields!

Comment: Maybe I should do this in a follow-up question, but how can I now do: 
for field in changed_fields: qs =MyModel.objects.filter(something=something), qs.update(***FIELD*** = F(field)), how to do the ***FIELD**?

Comment: Your code with `self` is working in my case. I just tried it. Please check if you have access to `self` when you are calling `filter()` or you have specified `self` in the function signature of `save()`.

Comment: It is working, thank you :) I also found the answer to my followup question, namely: **{field: F(field)} :) thank you again!

Comment: Great! Happy to help. :) Also check this link for updating multiple columns using F objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574187/update-multiple-columns-using-django-f-object

Comment: Newer django versions should check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106314/2711654) for an alternative to `get_all_field_names`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get the difference between the two instances with the help of **serializers** and [deepdiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/). Why serializer? as we have to get the whole nested data of the instance for comparison.

```
  from deepdiff import DeepDiff
  .
  .
  .
  old_data = modelserilaizer(instance1).data
  new_data = modelserilaizer(instance2).data
  instance_diff = DeepDiff(old_data, new_data, ignore_order=True)
  # output {'values_changed': {"root['item'][3]['rr'][2]['rate']": {'new_value': '0.03', 'old_value': '0.02'}}}
  if "values_changed" in instance_diff:
    # do you work here
```